# Does every real- analytic function defined in the neighborhood of$ x= 0$ must have a fixed point?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-functions, formal-power-series, fixed-points

let $f$ be a solution for an ODE and it is a real analytic function in defined in neighborhood of x=0 over $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Question:**
>   Does every real- analytic function defined in the neighborhood of$ x= 0$ must have a fixed point?

Comment: No.  Consider the function $x \mapsto x+1$.

Comment: sorry , i have a wrong typo for domain of definition of f, i me ant defined in the neighberhood of x=0

Comment: Xander's example is still valid.

Comment: The function cited above is analytic on any neighborhood of any point in $\mathbb{R}$.  Indeed, the form above *is* a power series representation of the function at zero (where most of the coefficients are zero).  It still has no fixed points.

Comment: Thanks what about the inverse if it has a fixed point must be a real Analytic  ?

Comment: I think you mean converse. And definitely not, can you think of a particularly simple counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. In fact, it has to only if it is lipschitzian with k<1, which is, for analytic functions: $|f'(x)|≤ k <1$

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider f(x) = exp(x) on ( - 1 , 1).